# grails: using "count()" on an instance instead

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a 1 to many relationship where each group has multiple positions, i.e.

```
Group -1----N- Position
```

class Group {  static hasMany = [postions: Position }

If I have a specific group instance, can't I count directly how many positions it has?  I.e. call some method group.positions.??

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to write this as an answer, because there may be a better solution, but `group.positions.size()` should work, since `group.positions` is just a list.  However, I think this will load all `Position`s into memory, so there hopefully is a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As OverZealous said you can call `group.positions.size()` but it will be very expensive for a large number of `Position`s since it will load all of them into memory just to count them, and then throw them away.

If your `Position` class has a back-reference to its owning `Group` class, e.g. `static belongsTo = [group: Group]`, then you can use this lightweight query:

```
def group = ...
int positionCount = Position.countByGroup(group)
```

If you don't have a bidirectional relationship, you can get the count via HQL:

```
def group = ...
int positionCount = Group.executeQuery(
    'select count(pos) from Group g ' +
    'inner join g.positions pos where g=:g', [g: group])[0]
```

Comment: +1 : really important to keep in mind, that performance difference btw countBy() and size()